# does specifying :first in jquery selector help performance?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

If I know there is at most 1 such object in my DOM, should I always append :first to the selector to speed up the lookup? I'm assuming the selection engine will stop as soon as it finds 1 matching element, but I'm not sure if the filter actually slow things down a bit.

Comment: I doubt it. I would imagine it gets all elements then check whether they are the first element in the parents container. (its right to left).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, as `:first` is not a standard CSS pseudo-class, and using it will cause your selector to not be passed to the native `querySelectorAll()` DOM function implemented by supporting browsers (assuming you don't use any other jQuery-only selector syntax).

jQuery will take the entire selector and parse it by itself (using Sizzle, most likely), which is leagues slower than letting the browser do the work.

Comment: It won't be so slow that the human eye can observe it, of course, but **in theory** it would harm performance rather than help. And again, this really only applies if the selector is supported by the browser's CSS engine and thus `querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: To your comment: If you try to debug a page, where `:first` pseudo-class selector are used, with respect of Developer Tools of Chrome you can enable in "Scripts" tab the "Pause on uncaught exceptions" button (at the bottom). On every selection with `:first` you would see exception in `querySelectorAll` (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/small-performance-improvements-in-selectors/#p26631)). In many cases `:first` can be replaced to `:first-child` or `:nth-of-type(1)` with will be quickly. One usage of `:first` is not really slow, but in the loop one can fill difference.

Answer (score 0):

One practice that's almost true; the more selectors you specify, the more the engine has to validate.

So, in your case, if you know it only has one, don't specify it.

But with declaration below, say, 100, you won't even notice it.